# How to understand the asymmetry between 포함하다 and 제외하다?

Tags: grammar

I was looking into how to express "except" or "including" in Korean and my main source for this question is [How to study Korean Lesson 71](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-3-intermediate-korean-grammar/lessons-67-75/lesson-71).

The word 포함하다 means "to include" whereas 제외하다 means "to exclude". Both of them are often used in passive form by changing 하다 into 되다. For example,

> 1. 이 뷔페가격은 포도주가 포함돼요 = This buffet price includes wine/Wine is included in the buffet price.
> 2. 이 뷔페가격은 포도주가 제외돼요 = This buffet price includes wine/Wine is not included in the buffet price.

But 포함하다 can be used within a sentence using 포함해(서). For example,

> 저를 포함해 여기에 네 명이 있어요 = Including me, there are four people here

On the other hand, 제외하다 can be used within a sentence using either 제외하고 or 제외한. For example,

> 나비를 제외한 모든 동물이 싫어요 = 나비를 제외하고 모든 동물이 싫어요 = Except for butterflies, I don’t like any/all animals.

The website linked at the beginning of the question says that though expressions like 포함하고 or 포함한 or 제외헤서 would be understood, there are not natural.

**I fail to understand that asymmetry. Is there a logical (i.e. grammatical) reason for it?**

From what I know of Korean grammar, 아/어/여서 means a consequence or a connection (rough English translation: "so"), while 아/어/여고 means a connection ("and") and (으)ㄴ is the adjective form of a descriptive verb.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give a shot with an example. I could make the following sentences, and they are symmetric *in Korean*, in that they are both *natual* (please comment if you do not agree).

> 저를 제외하고 여기에 네 명이 있어요 = Myself excluded, there are four people here
>
> 저를 포함하고 여기에 네 명이 있어요 = Myself included, there are four people here

While `Myself included, ...` is a common phrase in English, saying `Myself excluded, ...` would be *unnatural*. I'd like to argue that the tendency to use one form over the other is somwhat similar to this analogy.

To answer your question in **bold**, I do not believe that there is a logical/grammatical explanation to it.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the asymmetry in English. I am not sure I am following you example: are you saying that 제외하고 and 포함하고 are both correct and natural?

Comment: @Taladris - Indeed I am saying that 제외하고 and 포함하고 are both correct and natural. ~하고 is ~하다 + 고, which translates to do ~ and. In this case, both are correct in meaning and natural in use.

Comment: @Taladris, please consider selecting my answer if it was helpful

Comment: Your answer is useful, but it contradicts with @henry's answer. So I am not sure which one I should accept.

Comment: @Taladris, that's understandable.

Answer (score 3):

In everyday usage, I hear these more often in a less complex and formal context:

1. Including myself, there are four people

> 저까지 **합해서** 총 네 명 있어요

2. There are four people, not counting myself

> 저를 **빼고** 네 명 있어요

These are mathematical expressions of adding/combining (합하다) and subtracting (빼다). In this case, the asymmetry is more pronounced - it would be used for simple counts. 포함/제외 are more conceptual in nature where you could include/exclude intangibles like ideas, feelings, etc in addition to physical objects.

You could try looking up sample sentences with both and compare the nuances between 합하다/빼다 vs. 포함하다/제외하다.

Answer (score 2):

'제외해서' and '제외하고' are all correct.

The below four examples are all correct. Only the meanings are a bit different.

이것을 포함해서 다섯이에요. = It includes this and then they become five(natural). or They are five because this is included.

이것을 제외해서 다섯이에요. = They are five because this is excluded(natural). or It excludes this and then they become five.

이것을 포함하고 다섯이에요. = Including this, they are five.

이것을 제외하고 다섯이에요. = Except for this, they are five.

From your sentence '나비를 제외하고 모든 동물이 싫어요'

In this case, you can not say "나비를 제외해서 모든 동물이 싫어요."

Because '나비' is not a reason for disliking others.

Comment: I think there is a nuance in saying 포함해서/제외해서 here. It could imply that the act of excluding/including was performed in reality. 

i.e, 이것을 포함해서 다섯이에요 could imply 'Since this has been included, the set becomes five'.
Not always the case, but it could have a meaning in that direction.